# A table border look while still using rows and cols in bootstrap3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there an effective way to make a aesthetic grid look (1px borders all around cols like a table) while still having a row and column code.

For Example If I have this:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="tri-block col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
               <h4>Title</h4>
               <img src="" alt="" />
               <span>Description</span>
            </div>
            <div class="tri-block col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
               <h4>Title</h4>
               <img src="" alt="" />
               <span>Description</span>
            </div>
            ...
         </div>
```

I would like to have a grid looking border around things. If I add the CSS:

```
.tri-block {min-height:250px; padding:15px; text-align:center; border:1px solid #ddd;}
```

I get something close but I of course get double borders where the col touch. Is there a way to achieve this look that I am missing? My reason for this is because I still want the responsive breakdown and don't want to have a table I have to throw a "table-responsive" class on.

Comment: what about vertical margin ? top or bottom

Comment: yeah that works fine if I want them to be boxes with space in between. I was trying to have them all touch with a 1px border around everything and between everything.